# Cant figure out why my SASS wont work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

Hey I am trying to learn rails and following the rails tutorial. I am adding some elements to the apps style sheets using SCSS and this is what I am adding

```
/* miscellaneous */

  .debug_dump {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 45px;
    @include box_sizing;
  }
}
```

but when I go to view my it in a browser I receive this error

```
Mixin box-sizing is missing argument $boxmodel.
  (in /Users/<mynamehere>/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:110)

<html>
    <head>
      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                             "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

 Rails.root: /Users/<mynamehere>/workspace/sample_app
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is a link to my [github](https://github.com/claytonnewberry/sample_app) if you need to see anything else

Answer (score 3):

The error says, you need a argument for `box_sizing`.

So try `@include box-sizing(border-box);`.

Answer (score 3):

I made the same mistake. Check again [Listing 7.2](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code-mixin_and_debug), there's some extra code there before the "/* Miscellaneous */" part, where you declare what box_sizing is:

```
@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're declaring the mixin **after** the bootstrap & bootstrap-sprockets imports (i.e. ensure you're not declaring box_sizing **before** @import "bootstrap"). Bootstrap sass has a built-in box_sizing mixin that will take precedence over yours otherwise.

This isn't really covered in railsguide (there's no indicator that @import bootstrap introduces a conflicting mixin), so it's definitely an easy-to-make mistake.

I had the same issue with the same error message, and neither existing solution worked for me. In my case, I'd created an scss file for mixins and variables, and was importing it before bootstrap and bootstrap-sprockets. Moving it below them fixed the problem. So in your case, make sure your general order is:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap";

/* either @import your-file-containing-box-sizing-mixin; or: */

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after finishing working on the custom.scss in Listing 7.2 I updated custom.scss by adding the css sidebar code of Listing 7.11 and the forms css code of Listing 7.15 on top of the Sass mixin css code of Listing 7.2. So it looked like this.

```css
/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}
/* sidebar */

aside {
  section.user_info {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.gravatar_edit {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
/* mixins, variables, etc. */


@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

To Fix it I brought the Sass mixin css code of Listing 7.2 back to the top below the `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap"; but to be above the the css code of Listing 7.11 and  Listing 7.15. This fixed the problem for me, here is the top of the custom.scss when I finished.

```css
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";


/* mixins, variables, etc. */
@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
```